# Invalid Math Operator Declaration in LaTeX

Tags: math-operators

I am trying to define two operators, FM0 and FM4, using the code below
`\DeclareMathOperator{\FM0}{FM0}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\FM4}{FM4}`

But when I use them as

`\FM0(x) = \frac{\PP(x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A(i)}
 \FM4(x) = \frac{\PP(x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A(i)}`

I get this error: "Use of \FM doesn't match its definition"

Is it not allowed to use numbers in the name of math operators? Is there a simple way of defining these operators with numbers in them?

Comment: only letters are allowed in a multi-character "control sequence" (command name).  this is a basic tex requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...or you could define `\FM` as a `\mathop` that takes an argument.

Without `amsmath`, here is how:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\FM[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{FM#1}}\nolimits}% OR THIS
\newcommand\PP{\mathcal{P}}
\begin{document}
\[
 \FM0(x) = \frac{\PP(x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A(i)}
\]
\[
 \FM4(x) = \frac{\PP(x)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} A(i)}
\]
\end{document}
```

and with `amsmath`, egreg suggests an even better way:

```
\newcommand\FM[1]{\operatorname{FM#1}}
```

resulting, in either case, with

[image]

With the `\nolimits`, sub- and superscripts behave in the manner of `\DeclareMathOperator`, for example, `\FM0_i^2(x)`:

[image]

If you remove the `\nolimits` from the `\FM` definition (or use the star variant `\operator*` with the `amsmath` version), then it behaves like the star version, `\DeclareMathOperator*`:

[image]

Comment: Since the OP is clearly loading `amsmath`, you should too, so you can define `\newcommand\FM[1]{\operatorname{FM#1}}`, which is much simpler (and much better, for various reasons). Use `\operatorname*` for limits above and below.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\FMzero}{FM0}
\DeclareMathOperator{\FMiv}{FM4}
```

Comment: You mean `\FMzero` or similar instead of the two tokens `\FM` and `0`?

Comment: ah sure, didn't realize the 0 ...

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now, but I wished to have the operator name match the operator value.